# shellcode works but driver program doesnt run shellcode it just hangs

Tags: linux, gcc, nasm, shellcode, i386

I have shellcode which run without any error in assembly,but when I put that opcode in driver program and try to invoke it, it doesnt execute that shellcode, it just hangs by running previous C instruction like printing size of shell code.
**my system**
physical(hardware) system is x86_64
Linux lenova 4.19.0-9-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) i686 GNU/Linux
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1
NASM version 2.14

**shellcode.asm**

```
global _start

section .text

_start: 
    jmp msg

proc:   mov al, 4
    mov bl, 1
    pop ecx
    mov dl, 12
    int 0x80
    
    mov al, 1
    mov bl, 1
    int 0x80

msg: call proc
     db "HellowOworld"
section .data

nasm -felf32 shellcode.asm &&
ld shellcode.o -o shellcode &&
./shellcode          
HellowOworld (output)
```

**driver.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char shellcode[]="\xeb\x0f\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\x59\xb2\x0c\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\xb3\x01\xcd\x80\xe8\xec\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x77\x4f\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64";
int main(){
    printf("Shellcode of size %d \n", (int)strlen(shellcode));
    (*(void(*)())shellcode)();  
}

gcc -s -fno-stack-protector -z execstack driver.c
./a.out    
output=>
Shellcode of size 34 
(blankline and hungs)
```

Comment: You're probably creating a 64-bit executable, but your shellcode is 32-bit.  Try compiling driver.c with `-m32`

Comment: Typically when you include ASM, you would either link to the generated .o file, or, you would include the ASM in the C code and have GCC compile it.

Comment: Also, not necessarily your current bug, but the system call needs the whole 32-bit register to contain the correct value, and you're only loading the low bytes.  If `eax` contained `0xdeadbeef` before the call, then you are not going to invoke system call 4 but rather system call `0xdeadbe04` which of course will not work.  Likewise if `ebx` contains `0xd00dcafe` then you are going to be writing to file descriptor number `0xd00dca01`.  It'll require some creativity to achieve this without including any zero bytes in your shellcode, of course.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks second point worked it  .Primarily i was thinking to reduce opcode without bad characters , and almost i forgot it. adding on it i changed my os arch to 32bit recently , so this made me confused